# mod_jk configuration issue

Tags: tomcat, apache2, httpd.conf, mod-proxy, mod-jk

Little confused with this configuration.

I have loaded the mod_jk and provided following confguration

```
 <IfModule mod_jk.c>
  JKWorkersFile conf/workers.properties
  JkLogFile "/opt/test/logs/mod_jk.log.%m.%d.%Y"
  JkLogLevel info
  JkRequestLogFormat "%w %V %U %s %r %p %T"
  JkWatchdogInterval 60
  JkMount /example/* tomcat1
</IfModule>
```

My worker.properties

```
worker.tomcat1.port=8009
worker.tomcat1.host=localhost
worker.tomcat1.type=ajp13
worker.tomcat1.lbfactor=1
worker.tomcat1.retries=3
worker.tomcat1.connect_timeout=10000
worker.tomcat1.prepost_timeout=10000
worker.tomcat1.socket_keepalive=true
worker.tomcat1.socket_timeout=10
worker.tomcat1.connection_pool_timeout=600
```

Then  i need something like this, i can not use mod_proxy_ajp

All the requests from **tomcat web context context /example2/* to go tomcat  web context /example1/***, how to achieve this ?

Thanks for the help